# How to deal with Objects on Angular 4 using *ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm trying to populate a select option html with some data coming from a database. However, Angular 4 gives me the following error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

I have seen a few answers regarding this issue online, and some even on StackOverflow, however, I still wasn't able to solve it. Here's my code:

**JSON Object**

```
{
"organizations": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "organizationTypeId": 1,
        "name": "Hello",
        "abbreviation": "H"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "organizationTypeId": 1,
        "name": "Test",
        "abbreviation": "T"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Model**

```
export interface Organization {
id: number;
organizationTypeId: number;
name: string;
abbreviation: string;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<select [ngModel]="organizations">
    <option *ngFor="let org of organizations" [ngValue]="org.id">
        {{org.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Component**

```
export class UserAdditionalComponent implements OnInit  {

public organizations: Organization[];

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.net.get<Organization[]>(`Organization/GetAllUniversities/`).subscribe(t => {
        this.organizations = t;
            console.log(this.organizations);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.organizations, null, 4));
    }, err => {
        this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Erro', err.message);
        this.loaderService.display(false);
        });
    }
}
```

**Net Service Helper**

```
get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    let options = this.doHeaders();
    return this.doSub(this.http.get(this.doUrl(url), options));
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    try {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || [];
    }
    catch (ex) {
        return {
            isOk:res.ok,
            status: res.status,
            message:res.statusText
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to keep the generic Net Service Helper, since it is being used on many other parts of the application. I'm not sure how to deal with Object and *ngFor. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `<select [ngModel]="organizations">`, you should have something like `<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOrganizationId">`, where `selectedOrganizationId` is a class member.

Comment: @ConnorsFan , Thanks for your reply. I did change but my actual problem still persisted. I am not able to populate the select html. It is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if `this.organizations` is exactly equal to the following (as in your question):

```
{
"organizations": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "organizationTypeId": 1,
        "name": "Hello",
        "abbreviation": "H"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "organizationTypeId": 1,
        "name": "Test",
        "abbreviation": "T"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then the error makes sense because there is an object encapsulating your `organizations` array... So you would have to do: `ngFor="let org of this.organizations.organizations"`.

Or change your `this.net.get<Organization[]>('Organization/GetAllUniversities/')` return type to just an array... maybe:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  try {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.organizations || [];
   }
  ...
```

---

The best approach is to change

On Component:
`this.organizations;` to `this.data`

On HTML:
`*ngFor=let org of organizations` to
`*ngFor=let org of data.organizations`

Comment: Cool, your organizations.organizations worked. However, my Net Service helper is used in many components (not just organizations). Do you have any recommendation on how could i try to transform my Object response into an array then?

Comment: `this.organizations = t.organizations;` is what I would do. @LucasArruda then you can go back to just `ngFor="let org of this.organizations"` - I should've suggested this initially.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried that before, but that gives me a compile error (because Organization doesn't have .organizations). Probably due to the fact that this.organizations is actually a Organization[]. Anyway, i'll keep trying to fix, but you helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah that is tricky, because then you are going to have to update extractData. The other option just for code expressiveness is instead of doing `this.organizations = t;` do: `this.dataFromService = t;` then in your `*ngFor`: `this.dataFromService.organizations` <- at least it is way more readable ..

Comment: Glad I could help @LucasArruda. If you feel like this solved the question, please accept it as the answer :)